# Cron job que roda um bash script (que roda um script em python) se comportando diferente de quando executado manualmente

Tags: python, bash, cron

Ola..Eu tenho um script em python que plota dois graficos diferentes e que precisa ser rodado diariamente para atualizar esses graficos em um site

Os dados que sao usados por esse script, estao em um determinado diretorio em formato HDF

Eu criei um Bash script que copia os dados desse diretorio, converte para Netcdf, cola em outro diretorio, executa esse script em python e atualiza os graficos no site

Como eu disse, preciso que esses graficos sejam atualizados diariamente no site, por isso, programei esse bash script para ser rodado diariamente por crontab

O crontab esta de fato executando o bash script: Os dados estao sendo copiados, convertidos e colados...o script em python esta rodando e plotando os graficos soh que um deles, esta vindo com problema

Em um dos graficos ( o que plota a orbita de um satelite), eu preciso colocar a hora inicial e final de colteta de dados

Algo desse tipo:

Start: 00:00:38 UTC

End: 01:29:57 UTC

SOH QUE ...quando rodado por crontab, o que esta sendo plotado eh isso:

Start: 0 UTC

End: 4 UTC

Se eu rodo manualmente, ele funciona perfeitamente, e plota as horas do jeito certo

Essa eh a parte do meu script em python que esta plotando as horas:

```
  def cal_protime2dt(time):

    d = int(time % 100)
    m = int((time-d) % 10000)
    y = int(time-m-d)
    return dt.datetime(2000 + y//10000, m//100, d) + dt.timedelta(time % 1)

dates   = [cal_protime2dt(time[i]) for i in np.arange(len(time))]
datestr = [i.strftime('%H:%M:%S') for i in dates] 

t1=str(datestr[0])
t2=str(datestr[-1])

x, y = m(longitude[0], latitude[0])

m.plot(x, y, marker='D', color='m', markersize=2.1)
plt.text(-95,94.5, 'Start: {:} UTC \n\n\n '.format(t1), fontsize=5.55, color='m', ha='right',va='center')#, bbox=dict(facecolor='w', alpha=0.2))

z, w = m(longitude[-1], latitude[-1])
m.plot(z, w, marker='D', color='b', markersize=2.1)
plt.text(-97, 94.5, ' End: {:} UTC '.format(t2), fontsize=5.55, color='b',ha='right',va='center')
```

Esse eh o meu bash script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

  ontem=$(date --date="2 days ago" +"%Y-%m-%d");

  date=$ontem

  year=`date +"%Y"`

  previous_year=`date +"%Y" -d "-1 year"`

  h4=/mnt/raid/CALIPSO/SCRIPTS/

  dir=/mnt/raid/CALIPSO/DATA/NETCDF_TEMP/ 

  cd /mnt/raid/CALIPSO/DATA/L1.5/2017/

  cp CAL_LID_L15_Exp-Beta-V3-40.${date}T*.hdf /mnt/raid/CALIPSO/DATA/NETCDF_TEMP

  for i in ${dir}*.hdf; do ${h4}h4tonccf_nc4 $i; done

  python ${h4}CalipsoLatLonTimeLoop_TimTrack.py

  rsync -u -z -v -e "ssh -p 8222" /mnt/raid/CALIPSO/PICS/${year}* update@140.203.204.132:/home/www/html/rt/PICS/${year}/
  rsync -u -z -v -e "ssh -p 8222" /mnt/raid/CALIPSO/PICS/${previous_year}* update@140.203.204.132:/home/www/html/rt/PICS/${previous_year}/
```

E esse eh o jeito que eu programei o crontab para rodar:

```
  0 9 * * * /mnt/raid/CALIPSO/SCRIPTS/copy_convert_plot_update_twodaysago.sh
```

Alguem tem alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 0):

Como voce não colocou se esta usando user privilegiado ou não minha sugestão seria apontar na cron com qual user voce deseja que seu .py rode.
/1 * * * * update_user /var/www/web/includes/crontab/queue_process.php >> /var/www/web/includes/crontab/queue.log 2>&1

Comment: Ola! Obrigada! Mas acho que esse nao era o problema...Eu acabei conseguindo resolver....O problema estava na parte do codigo onde eu estava calculando as horas...Eu mudei isso de lugar, e voltou a funcionar!